# custom content providers in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm attempting to make a custom ContentProvider so that more than one application (activity?) has access to it. I have several questions about how to do this,

How do I declare in the code that it is a ContentProvider?
How do other applications (activities?) use or import the ContentProvider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the extensive [developer guide topic on content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), you can look at the [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) and [Note Pad sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) for information on creating your own content providers.

Comment: I went over the developer guide, but was anware of the Note Pad samples, thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! We're working on surfacing and raising awareness of these types of resources better.

Comment: Regarding the second part of the question... how do other applications use or import the ContentProvier?  The NotePad example does not cover this point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest of the application providing the content you would have:

```
<provider android:name="Inventory" android:authorities="com.package.name.Inventory" />
```

And in the application obtaining content

```
    String inventoryItem = "dunno";
       try {
          Uri getItem = Uri.parse(
            "content://com.package.name.Inventory/database_items");
            String[] projection = new String[] { "text" };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(getItem, projection, null, null, null);
            if (null != cursor && cursor.moveToNext()) {
              int index = cursor.getColumnIndex("text");
              inventoryItem = cursor.getString(index));     
            }
            cursor.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

In an external program, this would return the item listed under item_socks, but this is just a general example of having only one item listed with that name. You would be querying a database table named database_items that looks something like:

id | title | text

1 | item_socks | brown pair red stripe

inventoryItem would then be equal to "brown pair red stripe"